# What is this matrix/operator notation $\otimes$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, convex-geometry

Some notes I'm reading say that:

> $$x = \sum_{i=1}^m c_i\langle x,u_i\rangle u_i$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (where $c_i > 0$ are positive numbers and $u_i$'s are unit vectors) **can be equivalently written** in **matrix (or operator)** notation as $$\sum_{i=1}^m c_i u_i\otimes u_i = I_n$$ where $I_n$ is the identity map on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and for any unit vector $u$, $u\otimes u$ is the rank-one orthogonal projection onto the span of $u$, i.e. the map $x\mapsto \langle x,u\rangle u$. The trace of this projection is $1$.

So, I haven't seen the above notation $\otimes$ earlier - and I'm a little confused what it means? Could someone help me understand?

What is the meaning of **rank-one orthogonal projection** here, and what does the operator really do? How is this equivalent to the first condition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/relation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [Outer/Tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) and defined by $u \otimes v = uv^\top$ or alternatively, you can think of it as the function

$$ (u \otimes v)(x) = \langle v, x \rangle u, $$

which is of course what you get when you multiply $uv^\top$ and $x$ together.

Note: there is also a Kronecker product which uses the same symbol and the relationship is

$$ u \otimes_{\rm out} v = u \otimes_{\rm kr} v^\top. $$

The [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of two column vectors $(a_i), (b_j)$ is a vector whose $(in + j)$-th entry is $a_ib_j$. The outer product is a matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $a_ib_j$.

Answer (score 0):

In particular, if u and v are written as "column" matrices, $u= \begin{pmatrix}u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v= \begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix}$, then $v^T= \begin{pmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & v_3\end{pmatrix}$, a"row" matrix, and
$uv^T= \begin{pmatrix}u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & v_3\end{pmatrix}= $$\begin{pmatrix} u_1v_1 & u_1v_2 & u_1v_3 \\ u_2v_1 & u_2v_2 & u_2v_3 \\ u_3v_1 & u_3v_2 & u_3v_3 \end{pmatrix}$, a 3 by 3 matrix.